# Magento 2 CE maximum numbers of connection supported at same time

Tags: magento2

I have a question related to Magento 2 CE.
Because it doesn't support master/slave database do you know how many simultaneously  customers can order at the same time?
Or how many connections support .

We have few products on website and we have few customers (10 .000) but we have a lot of orders.

I don't know if i should recommend CE or EE and my consern is related to the fact that database cannot scale.

Thank You,
Ovidiu